# How to set (import) oembed's ctools exportable settings as defaults for the module programmatically?

Tags: hooks, features, chaos-tool-suite, media

Oembed provides defaults for some providers (e.g. youtube, twitter etc) out of the box. It also provides the ability to export each provider's settings through the UI. I have added a new URL pattern ("scheme") on youtube's settings on /admin/config/media/oembed/provider/list/youtube/edit and have also exported these, it looks like that:

```
$provider = new stdClass();
$provider->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default provider disabled initially */
$provider->name = 'youtube';
$provider->title = 'YouTube';
$provider->endpoint = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed';
$provider->scheme = 'http://*.youtube.com/watch*
  http://*.youtube.com/v/*
  https://*.youtube.com/watch*
  https://*.youtube.com/v/*
  http://youtu.be/*
  http://*.youtube.com/user/*
  http://*.youtube.com/*#*/*
  http://m.youtube.com/watch*
  http://m.youtube.com/index*
  http://*.youtube.com/profile*
  http://*.youtube.com/view_play_list*
  http://*.youtube.com/playlist*
  my_addition_here';
```

The problem is that no feature is picking up oembed's settings. This only works with custom providers I have created myself, not default ones already provided by the module.
This seems to be related to the problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1543894. I have tried the patch ie adding

```
'api' => array(
  'owner' => 'oembedcore',
  'api' => 'oembedcore',
  'minimum_version' => 1,
  'current_version' => 1,
),
```

to _oembedcore_provider_schema_1() or even by altering the schema with a hook and also

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 */
function mymodule_ctools_plugin_api($module = NULL, $api = NULL) {
  if ($module == "oembedcore" && $api == "oembedcore") {
    return array("version" => "1");
  }
}
```

according to https://www.drupal.org/node/1543894#comment-8981081 but this doesn't seem to make features aware of oembed's settings.

Another related issue, https://www.drupal.org/node/1330140 suggests this addition:

```
function my_module_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['oembedcore_preset']['export']['api'] = array(
    'owner' => 'oembedcore',
    'api' => 'oembedcore',
    'minimum_version' => 1,
    'current_version' => 1,
  );
}
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect really.

There's also a hook that's supposed to alter a provider's attributes used by oembedembedly, 'hook_oembedprovider_alter':

```
function oembedembedly_oembedprovider_alter(&$providers) {
  foreach ($providers as $host => $patterns) {
    if (strpos($host, '*') === 0) {
      $new_host = drupal_substr($host, 1);
      if (!empty($providers[$new_host])) {
        $providers[$new_host] = array_merge($providers[$new_host], $patterns);
      }
      else {
        $providers[$new_host] = $patterns;
      }
      unset($providers[$host]);
    }
  }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work either when I apply it in my own module.

How can I pursuade oembed module to pick up my exported overriden settings for one of its default 'providers'?